# play framework 2.3.6 save logs to h2 database

Tags: java, database, logging, playframework-2.0, h2

I need to save all generated logs in h2 db, I saw some mention of database appenders at [play logging documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaLogging#Appenders) but I can't find any resources or examples on how to configure the database appender in the logger.xml file.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a way to configure the db appender through [this : db appender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#DBAppender) link, setting 
`<configuration debug="true">` gives you any errors while saving the logs to db,

I'm still getting `Table "LOGGING_EVENT" not found;` error, do I have to manually create those tables ?

Comment: I went with writing scripts in evolution file to create those tables, if anyone has better ideas, I'm all ears :)